# typedef works, 'using =' doesn't

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef, using

I have a piece of code which, simplified a bit, amounts to the following which compiles and works correctly.

```
template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
struct factory_function {
  typedef function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)> type;
};

template <typename Interface, typename Implementer, typename... Args>
shared_ptr<Interface> create_function(Args... args) {
  return make_shared<Implementer>(args...);
}

template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
  int register_factory(identifier id, typename factory_function<Interface, Args...>::type factory) {
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  register_factory<Iface>(1000, create_function<Iface, Impl>);
  return 0;
}
```

But when trying to use the newer `using ... =` construct instead of a typedef in a struct like this:

```
template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
using factory_function = function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)>;
```

and then change `typename factory_function<Interface, Args...>::type` into `factory_function<Interface, Args...>`, I get a compile error:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
foo.cc:31:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘register_factory(int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   register_factory<Iface>(1000, create_function<Iface, Impl>);
                                                         ^
foo.cc:31:61: note: candidate is:
foo.cc:17:5: note: template<class Interface, class ... Args> int register_factory(identifier, factory_function<Interface, Args ...>)
 int register_factory(identifier id, factory_function<Interface, Args...> factory) {
     ^
foo.cc:17:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cc:31:61: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<std::shared_ptr<Iface>(Args ...)>’ and ‘std::shared_ptr<Iface> (*)()’
   register_factory<Iface>(1000, create_function<Iface, Impl>);
                                                         ^
foo.cc:31:61: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function ‘create_function<Iface, Impl>’
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the full, compilable test case, compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 foo.cc`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

typedef int identifier;

template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
struct factory_function {
  typedef function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)> type;
};
//template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
//using factory_function = function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)>;

template <typename Interface, typename Implementer, typename... Args>
shared_ptr<Interface> create_function(Args... args) {
  return make_shared<Implementer>(args...);
}

template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
int register_factory(identifier id, typename factory_function<Interface, Args...>::type factory) {
//int register_factory(identifier id, factory_function<Interface, Args...> factory) {
}

class Iface {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Impl : public Iface {
public:
  virtual void foo() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  register_factory<Iface>(1000, create_function<Iface, Impl>);
  return 0;
}
```

The commented lines show what is *not* working.

Comment: Please provide a *compilable* testcase (no skipping the includes, typedefs, etc).

Comment: Done. See the new update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work by combining the two approaches ;)

```
template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
struct fa_fu_helper {
  typedef function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)> type;
};

template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
using factory_function = typename fa_fu_helper<Interface, Args...>::type;
```

Comment: This is how I fixed my problem in the end, although Jarod42's answer and comments made me understand what the root of the problem was.

Comment: just to make sure, you *can* do `using type = function</ *bla */>;` inside the `fa_fu_helper` struct

Comment: Then you will have to still use it like fa_fu_helper<..>::type, won't you?

Answer (score 6):

With `int register_factory(identifier id, typename factory_function<Interface, Args...>::type factory)`, compiler cannot deduce type `Interface` and `Args`, so the call to `register_factory<Iface>(1000, create_function<Iface, Impl>);` is explicitly `int register_factory(identifier id, typename factory_function<Interface>::type);`

With the alternative definition (with using) `int register_factory(identifier id, factory_function<Interface, Args...>`, compiler have to try to deduce `Args`(`Interface` is explicitly set to `Iface`) but unfortunately, a conversion is needed and compiler failed (`std::shared_ptr<Iface> (*)()` is not an exact match for any `function<std::shared_ptr<Iface>(Args...)>`)

A workaround is your second solution is to force the type of `create_function<Iface, Impl>` to a `std::function`. the following may help so:

```
template <typename R, typename...Args>
std::function<R(Args...)> make_function(R (*f)(Args...))
{
    return f;
}
```

And later:

```
register_factory<Iface>(1000, make_function(create_function<Iface, Impl>));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand this. When I call `register_factory<Iface>(...)`, I'm explicitly setting `Interface` to `Iface` and `Args` to an empty list. What is it the compiler needs to deduce?

Comment: No, as when you call `make_shared<Implementer>(args...)`, you fix `Implementer` but deduction of `args` still occurs.

Comment: `create_function<Iface, Impl>`: here `Args` are fixed and shouldn't be deduced.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, when we have `typename factory_function<Interface, Args...>::type` the compiler has to match `std::shared_ptr<Iface> (*)()` to `function<std::shared_ptr<Iface>(Args...)>` which is done through a cast, because `...::type` is a type. But with "using ... =", `factory_function<Interface, Args...>` is a template which needs to be matched first, and then the type is determined. So the compiler cannot do the deduction and fails. Am I right?

Comment: @Constructor: `create_function<Iface, Impl>` is fixed but it is a pointer to function and not directly a `std::function`, and which `std::function` is the correct one ? (compiler would have to check a infinite number of possibility).

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right, of course. I haven't noticed `std::function`.

Comment: @Elektito: nearly, in the first case it has to convert `std::shared_ptr<Iface> (*)()` to `function<std::shared_ptr<Iface>()>` (without `Args...`)